# jquery scroll to top icon overlapping footer

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following code for scroll to top, which work fine when click to scroll to top. 
The problem I am having with the scroll to top button should always be positioned at the bottom corner of the page when there is no page footer and when there is a page footer i want it positioned 20px above the page footer.

How do i do that correctly?.

here is my code below and fiddle link here [FIDDLE here](https://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/cxm85wqm/11/)

JS

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
        }
    }); 

    $('.scrollup').click(function(){
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
        return false;
    });
```

CSSS

```
.scrollup{
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    opacity:0.3;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:250px;
    right:100px;
    display:none;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    background: url('icon_top.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: do you have a fiddle or codepen example?

Comment: If the actual scrolling works but just the styling is wrong, then the title is misleading as is the jquery tag and code.

Comment: @FlipFloop here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/cxm85wqm/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you ll have to check if footer exists in document. 
And then if footer is visible in your broswer you have to adjust the position of your scroll link

> Check out the sollution to this question -> [Check if element is visible after scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)

```js
    function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var $elem = $(elem);
    var $window = $(window);

    var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();

    var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        if($("footer").length){
            if(isScrolledIntoView($("footer"))){
            $('.scrollup').css("bottom",$("footer").outerHeight() +"px")
          }
          else{
            $('.scrollup').css("bottom","0px")
          }
        }
        $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
      } else {
        $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
      }
    });

    $('.scrollup').click(function() {
      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
      }, 600);
      return false;
    });
```

```css
.scrollup {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  opacity: 0.3;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 100px;
  display: none;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background: url('icon_top.png') no-repeat;
  bordeR: 1px solid red;
  background-color:red;
  content:UP;
}
footer{ border:1px solid red; padding:50px 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p><p>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</p>
<a href="#" class="scrollup">Scroll</a>
<!-- footer --->
<footer>
<h2>
This is the footer. up arrow should be alway above the footer . 
</h2>  
</footer>
```

a working example here : https://jsfiddle.net/00f7p7ay/1/

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question:

```
.scrollup {
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   opacity: 0.3;
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
   display: block;
   text-indent: -9999px;
   background: url('icon_top.png') no-repeat;
   border: 1px solid red;
   background-color:red;
   content:UP;
}
```

See the updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cxm85wqm/14/)

**Not sure about the second part at the moment.**